# Number Appears after Array Stored in SESSION

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm doing a print_r on a array stored on a session variable and for some unknown reason it's adding a number after the array prints.

Example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 868
    [userid] => 868
)
1
```

If I do a print_r directly in the function itself and before the variable gets stored on session variable, it doesn't add that number 1.

Solution:

Almost at the same time as Paolo answered my question correctly I found the causing code.

A simple echo on print_r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the code you are using to do this around `print_r`? The most common reason for getting a 1 is when you try to print a boolean:

```
$my_bool = true;
print $my_bool; // will be printed as 1
print_r($my_bool); // will also be printed as 1
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. You're probably echoing out the return value of print_r() which is 'true'.  You'll have to set print_r() to return the formatted text rather that its success or failure.

```
echo "Session: ".print_r($_SESSION,true)."<br />\n";
```

Comment: Strange, I would have guessed this was the cause but the other answer (Paolo Bergantino) has been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Beside using `print_r` or `vardump`, you should consider using [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) or [PHP Quick Profiler](http://particletree.com/features/php-quick-profiler/) to help you debugging and displaying variable's value.

With [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/), you can display the value into Firebug's console. Using, [PHP Quick Profiler](http://particletree.com/features/php-quick-profiler/), there will be a console added at the bottom of the page that can be used to display any value that you need.