# Having more issues with mysqli. Numerical data in results

Tags: php, mysql

When I do a print_r, I get a number 1 between the array blocks. I have no idea where it is coming from.

This is causing errors in my log. I can fix this by testing with is_array but I want to know where this is coming from.

I'm making two queries but yet I have a third array in there. What is going on?????

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 2
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 110
    [type] => 0
)
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 1
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 12
    [type] => 0
)
1                    <-------------------------------------HERE
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 1
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 1
    [type] => 0
)
```

---

```
$this->conn->query("CALL phoneIsRegistered($phone,@phone)");

$res = $this->conn->query("SELECT @phone");
```

---

```
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query) or die('Error: '.mysqli_error($this->conn));

    if($result)
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            if($row)
            {
                print_r($row);
            }
        }
        $this->disconnect();
    }
```

This is what the loop looked like before I began trying to find this.

```
    $this->connect();
    $result = mysqli_query($this->_conn, $query) or die('Error: '.mysqli_error($this->conn));

    if($result){
        $i=0;
        $res = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            if($row){
                $res[$i++] = $row;
            }
        }
        $this->disconnect();
        return $res;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet you a beer that at some point while adding those mysqli_results to your array, you are pushing a `true` value into the array, maybe when the variable you work on turns out *not* to be a valid mysql_result or due to some other misdirected check or comparison.

You would have to show us the complete loop you are using to fill the array.

Comment: Hi Pekka, you helped me last night. Thanks for lending a hand. Let me grab the complete loop before I started pulling everything apart. brb.

Comment: There you go Pekka. I've posted it above

Comment: BTW: The true value, if that's what it is, is not inside the array. It's outside the array block which is why it is so disturbing to me.

Comment: Really odd, I can't see anything wrong with the code. Can you pinpoint where the `1` comes from by doing random outputs around the code? Is it the result of a single `print_r()` command`? fetch_object() is not supposed to return `1` or `true` in any circumstance.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now and you know what? I'm not seeing this number value when I do a print_r() inside my db class. So.. when the object is returned, somewhere along the way, it is picking up this value. I'm baffled...

Comment: Pekka, I'm getting this error now: Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object. What exactly does this mean? This is referring to the same line in the while loop that gathers the results.

Comment: I take it this is not important any more, seeing that you are on a different point already in your 2nd question?

Comment: Generally Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object
Means the SQL returned an error.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I am using print_r I see these 1's come up a lot also. I believe that this page would answer your question.

[Number Appears after Array Stored in SESSION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720161/number-appears-after-array-stored-in-session)

It should not hurt anything....

Answer (score 0):

Beside using `print_r` or `vardump`, you should consider using [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) or [PHP Quick Profiler](http://particletree.com/features/php-quick-profiler/) to help you debugging and displaying variable's value.

With [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/), you can display the value into Firebug's console. Using, [PHP Quick Profiler](http://particletree.com/features/php-quick-profiler/), there will be a console added at the bottom of the page that can be used to display any value that you need.