# Can someone tell me why I am getting a bool value back out of this proc?

Tags: mysql

I have several procedures on this machine and this is the only query that is giving me a boolean value (at least I think it is a boolean value) in my PHP code. When I substitute this procedure with another one, this value goes away. Is there a problem with this code the way I have it?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `phoneIsRegistered`
(IN iPhone bigint(10), OUT oPhone bigint(10))
BEGIN

        SELECT
          phone
        FROM
            user
        WHERE
            phone = iPhone
        INTO
            oPhone;
END;
```

---

Here is what the array looks like with this value I'm talking about.

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 2
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 110
    [type] => 0
)
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 1
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 12
    [type] => 0
)
1                    <-------------------------------------HERE
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 1
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 1
    [type] => 0
)
```

Comment: Isn't this the same question you posted earlier? Without the code that prints the results, we can't help you.

Comment: yes, seems to be the same question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013668/having-more-issues-with-mysqli-numerical-data-in-results ). jim: please update/edit that other question instead of opening a duplicate one.

Comment: Jimmy, if you head over to the other post, you will see more code than  you would need. I've literally posted code and then some. Yes, I'm the same poster.

Comment: Even after posting the code, nobody seems to know where this value is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there's a syntax error, in that you're using ';' both for the inner query and the create procedure. You need to "DELIMITER='//';" before the procedure and then use "END//". But still use ';' on the inner query.

```
DELIMITER '//'
CREATE PROCEDURE...
  ..
END//
DELIMITER ';'
```

Comment: Hi Tor, the proc is already created and when I view the DDL after it has been created, this is what it shows. When I created it, I did exactly what you suggested. Can you please elaborate a bit on the semicolon? I don't understand.

Comment: I just remade the proc using your suggestion. I'm going to test it now.

Comment: Nope... Even after deleting the proc and remaking it again, I am still getting this value in my PHP code.